# Как запретить пересылать сообщения бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть telegram бот, который отправляет информацию, направленную на каждого пользователя по-отдельности. Столкнулся с проблемой пересылки сообщений бота в другие беседы и другим людям.
По итогу вопрос, как запретить пересылку сообщений бота другим людям, группам?

Есть вариант сделать сообщения временными, самоудаляющимися, но хотелось бы всё же обойтись без этого.

Comment: Вроде как подобное не запретить. В любом случае пользовать может сделать скриншот экрана и так же отправить эту информацию)

Comment: @essle - в сообщениях есть ссылка, так что скриншот мало чем поможет. Тем более инфа имеет ценность первые 10 минут.